# How see all collision objects in rviz?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm working with panning scenes. I have done a "world interface" class in C++.
My code works, I can iterate all collision objects and attached collision objects, but I can't see this objects in Rviz.

Well, I have a marker with attached_objects topic, and I can see when an object is attached, but I can't see any collision object.

I have read in a tutorial that said somethin like "Launch the display for known model markers" with: roslaunch planning_environment display_planner_collision_model.launch but this file doesn't exits.

How can I see all the scene object?

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49623/how-see-all-collision-objects-in-rviz?/) by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) on 2012-12-03**:
In my code, I add some collision objects into the world, and after a get_planning_scene, I can iterate all the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think there is any direct link between the environment_server and rviz nodes.

When you say that you are adding collision objects to the environment, I assume that you are publishing them on a /collision_object topic; This will add them to the world. If you are adding them by calling set_planning_scene_diff, then they are not permanently added to the world.

So, assuming you are adding them permanently to the world via the /collision_object topic, I think you will need something custom to show them in rviz. I suggest that whatever node you use to publish on /collision_object should also publish a Marker or MarkerArray using the same resource (For example, if you are adding a mesh object for collision, use the same mesh file published to a marker).

I am working on something similar right now, I will try to remember to remember to post some example code when I finish.

---

Originally posted by [dsolomon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2369/dsolomon/) with karma: 253 on 2012-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0